# Gson deserialize Java.util.Date with timezone

Tags: java, date, timezone, gson

I deserialize a json string with date:

```
"created_at": "2015-12-24T17:41:54+01:00",
```

I set date format for gsonBuilder:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").create();
```

The deserialization works without crash; unfortunately when I print the result it's not correct:

```
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
String str = ft.format(response.createdAt);
```

The result is:

```
2015-12-24T11:41:54-0500
```

instead of:

```
2015-12-24T17:41:54+01:00
```

Comment: get rid of the `Z` and have it in your local TZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't set the timezone only added a Z to the end of the date/time, so it will look like a GMT date/time but this doesn't change the value.

Set the timezone to GMT and it will be correct.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

Comment: Great ! Thank you Sazzad !

Answer (score 2):

## java.time

The accepted Answer is correct. But outdated. The java.text.SimpleDateFormat and java.util.Date classes have been outmoded by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework added to Java 8 and later. Much easier to use and more sensible.

### ISO 8601

The format of your input string complies with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. The java.time classes use ISO 8601 as their default formats when parsing/generating string representations of date-time values.

```
String input = "2015-12-24T17:41:54+01:00";
```

### Offset-From-UTC

That input string includes an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) of `+01:00`, meaning an hour ahead of UTC.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse ( input );
ZoneId z = zdt.getZone ();
```

### Offset versus Time Zone

But that offset is *not* a time zone. A time zone is an offset *plus* rules for handling anomaly adjustments such as Daylight Saving Time (DST). So you may well want to assign [a specific time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) you have in mind as being intended by that string. Perhaps you intended [Amsterdam time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Amsterdam).

We can apply a time zone to get another [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object. This pattern of creating a new object based on an old object’s values rather than changing the old values directly is known as [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).

A [`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) is a full time zone in java.time. Its subclass [`ZoneOffset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) is for simple offset-from-UTC values without the adjustment rules.

```
ZoneId zoneIdAmsterdam = ZoneId.of ( "Europe/Amsterdam" );
ZonedDateTime zdtAmsterdam = zdt.withZoneSameInstant ( zoneIdAmsterdam );
```

## `toString`

When you call `toString` such as in a `System.out.println`, java.time classes generate a String representation of the date-time value using [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

Note that java.time extends ISO 8601 by appending the name of an assigned time zone in square brackets in addition to the offset-from-UTC number. For example, `[Europe/Amsterdam]`.

```
    System.out.println ( "zdt: " + zdt + " at zoneId z: " + z + " adjusted to zoneIdAmsterdam: " + zoneIdAmsterdam + " is zdtAmsterdam: " + zdtAmsterdam );
```

> zdt: 2015-12-24T17:41:54+01:00 at zoneId z: +01:00 adjusted to zoneIdAmsterdam: Europe/Amsterdam is zdtAmsterdam: 2015-12-24T17:41:54+01:00[Europe/Amsterdam]

### `Instant`

Generally in our business logic and data storage we work strictly in UTC, applying a time zone only for presentation to the user. For this purpose, pass and store an instance of the [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class. This class represents a moment on the timeline in UTC.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();
```